# Application hosted WCF service freezes after 3.5h

Tags: wcf

I've been chasing an issue for a while now.  We have a (complex) WCF service hosted in an application, with a GUI client connecting to it.  We've been experiencing freezes in the GUI and after adding logging and heartbeat service requests between the client and server, I observe the following:

I see continuous sent / received messages in the log of the client and server.  Then, after 3h32min (give or take a second or two), I see the client log messages, but not the server.  So I'll see sent, sent, sent, sent... from the client, but no receive message from the server.  This lasts for about a minute or two, and then I'll see a number of received, received, received, ... messages.  It's as if the WCF requests got stuck somewhere and then all got delivered at the same time.

I've implemented fault and exception handling in the server, and it does not get triggered.  I've experimented with singleton and per call instances of the service.  Nothing seems to make a difference to when the error occurs.

At this point I am open to any suggestions on what to try / measure / experiment with.

Comment: I'd suspect a GC run blocking the service, but GC'ing for minutes at a time would seem unlikely. Still, always worth running a memory profiler on it to see what it's up to.

Comment: Please show your codes of client calls and the heardbeat/logging. I would suspect resource leaks at this stage, unless your codes prove otherwise.

Comment: If I change the GC model to disable concurrent and register for notifications, I get *very* few notifications if I leave the system in a steady state.  By this I mean not even once an hour.  It doesn't sound right to me, but I'm no expert at this low level.  When the system experiences the freezing, Task Manager shows memory usage at around 40%, but CPU goes high.

Comment: Circling back to this issue, I recompiled our solution on VS 2013 and targeted the projects to .Net 4.5.  This seemed to resolve the issue as it has never manifested again on that configuration.  I then used the original executables built with VS 2010 (no recompile) and just upgraded the computer to .Net 4.5.  That also seemed to fix the problem.  So it looks like I ran into some subtle bug in .Net.